# Enabling browser side caching for rails 3.1 app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a quite a big jpg image file and few css files, and these are not going to change for every reload but every time it is loading the full imgae instead of caching in the browser, I tried changing the config like config.action_controller.perform_caching = true etc but nothing seems to help. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'd love an answer for this as well :(

Comment: I think I've already added caching on my app. Read these: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-the-memcache-addon

I'm not sure if it's browser caching but it is caching my static files!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me in my production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2419200"
```

That is 4 weeks which I figure is good enough.

Comment: To avoid the need to remember how much exactly is 2419200 seconds, it's possible to use ActiveSupport: ``config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=#{1.month.to_i}"``